# How to make list of positions if total salary of all persons more than ...?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to make list of persons where will be persons, if total salary of all persons more than 5000 (for example), or if total salary will be less return empty list

I am try to use java.util.Collection.stream()

```
public static List<Person> filterPositions (List<Person> persons, Predicate<Person> predicate) {
        return positions.stream().filter(predicate).collect(
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.summingInt( ...
```

But I have no idea how continue this code

Comment: This isn't clear. What _is a_ `Position`? What _is a_ `Person`? What do you want **exactly** - preferably with an example.

Comment: ok must be more clear, can you look again?

Comment: I want to return list of persons, if total salary of all persons  will be more than 5000

Comment: @MaxUsanin, and what do you want to return if total salary is less?

Comment: if total salary is less? - empty list

Comment: So `if(positions.stream().mapToInt(Person::getSalary).sum() > 5000) return positions; else return Collections.emptyList();` will satisfy you?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it seems I misunderstood what you wanted. Could you clarify by maybe posting your `Person` and `Position` classes?

Comment: .mapToInt(Person::getSalary).sum() > 5000)   - but it is not total salary - it is salary for each person or not?

Comment: @MaxUsanin, it's still unclear. Probably you can write Java-7 code which makes what do you want (and we will translate it to Stream API)? Or please give us concrete example with concrete input data and desired output.

Comment: @TagirValeev ok what about this? SUM(salary) > 5000 return List<Person> with persons or if SUM(salary) < 5000  return  List<Person> but empty

Comment: You are not talking about `Position` anymore, is that normal? So we have as input a list of `Person`. Each person has a salary. Are we summing the salary over the list of persons? If so, [Tagir Valeev's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017060/how-to-make-list-of-positions-if-total-salary-of-all-persons-more-than#comment53857575_33017060) gives you want you want.

Comment: @Tunaki  I am sorry, now is normal - only Person, "Are we summing the salary over the list of persons?" - yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking too complicated…

```
public static List<Person> filterPositions(
    List<Person> persons, Predicate<Person> predicate) {

    return persons.stream().filter(predicate).mapToInt(Person::getSalary).sum() > 5000?
        persons: Collections.emptyList();
}
```

If you want to return a filtered list you may use either:

```
public static List<Person> filterPositions(
    List<Person> persons, Predicate<Person> predicate) {

    return persons.stream().filter(predicate).mapToInt(Person::getSalary).sum() > 5000?
        persons.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList()):
        Collections.emptyList();
}
```

or

```
public static List<Person> filterPositions(
    List<Person> persons, Predicate<Person> predicate) {

    persons = persons.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return persons.stream().mapToInt(Person::getSalary).sum() > 5000?
        persons: Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Either variant has an advantage depending on whether the condition is true. While the first variant omits the collecting operation in the case that it is not, the second variant omits the second filtering operation in the case it is. Thus the preference depends on the likelihood of the condition being true. Or how expensive the filter or how big the resulting list is expected to be.

---

An entirely different option arises, if you are allowed to modify the incoming list:

```
/** modifies {@code persons} list. */
public static void filterPositions(
    List<Person> persons, Predicate<Person> predicate) {

    persons.removeIf(predicate.negate());
    if(persons.stream().mapToInt(Person::getSalary).sum() <= 5000)
        persons.clear();
}
```

Comment: Can we make your answer more complicated ?  Like .filter(predicate).mapToInt(Person::getSalary + Person::getPremium).sum()

Comment: You will have to use `.mapToInt(p -> p.getSalary() + p.getPremium())` but that’s not a complication as the principle remains the same.

Comment: Thank you. I want to ask one more question .. can we put all this manipulations inside filter(predicate) ? Because you could noticed all this working like filter

Comment: I’m not sure what you want to achieve. Creating a filter that accept all or rejects all, depending on a total number, is not really a useful idea. The only way to calculate the total number is to process all items and you don’t want to repeat this operation for every item.

Comment: when .sum() > 5000 they return whole list but I have .filter(predicate) - it is means list is restricted.. how  can I return only persons.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.<Person>toList()) ?